# How to find substrings in log file and increment the counter using dos batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, token, dhcp

Can anybody help me in making the windows batch file to find the substring from the log file. Sample of the log.log file is as below

```
ID,Date,Time,Description,IP Address,Host Name,MAC Address
10,02/21/14,00:29:45,Assign,172.20.55.50,PC1,123456789AB1,
31,02/21/14,00:29:45,DNS Update,172.20.55.50,PC1,123456789AB1,
10,02/21/14,00:29:45,Assign,172.30.55.50,PC2,123456789AB2,
31,02/21/14,00:29:45,DNS Update,172.30.55.50,PC1,123456789AB2,
10,02/21/14,00:29:45,Assign,172.20.56.60,PC3,123456789AB3,
10,02/21/14,00:29:45,Assign,172.30.55.60,PC4,123456789AB4,
**11,02/21/14,00:30:45,Assign,172.30.55.10,PC2,123456789AB5,**
**11,02/21/14,00:30:46,Assign,172.30.55.10,PC2,123456789AB5,**
**31,02/21/14,00:00:37,DNS Update Failed,172.17.110.13,TAR-CAR-051180L.WTPK.local,-1,**
```

This is basically DHCP log file. The objective is to count number of New Assign IP requests (whose ID is 10) and number of renewal IP requests (whose ID is 11).

For ID 10, if the IP starts with 172.20.55 or 172.20.56 it should increment in the counter "NewPoolA" and if the IP starts with 172.30.55 or 172.30.56 it should increment in "NewPoolB".

Similarly for ID 11 if the IP starts with 172.20.55 or 172.20.56 it should increment in the counter "RenewPoolA" and if the IP starts with 172.30.55 or 172.30.56 it should increment in "RenewPoolB".

so far what I have done is below

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a NewPoolA=0
set /a NewPoolB=0
set /a RenewPoolA=0
set /a RenewPoolB=0

for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (log.log) do (
    if %%a equ 10 (
        rem if %%e contains 172.20.55 (
            set /a NewPoolA += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem else if %%e contains 172.20.56 (
            set /a NewPoolA += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem else if %%e contains 172.30.55 (
            set /a NewPoolB += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem else if %%e contains 172.30.56 (
            set /a NewPoolB += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem -------- if id 10 and not match any condition then
        goto someLabel
    ) else if %%a equ 11 (
        rem if %%e contains 172.20.55 (
            set /a RenewPoolA += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem else if %%e contains 172.20.56 (
            set /a RenewPoolA += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem else if %%e contains 172.30.55 (
            set /a RenewPoolB += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem else if %%e contains 172.30.56 (
            set /a RenewPoolB += 1
            goto someLabel
        )
        rem -------- if id 11 and not match any condition then
        goto someLabel
    )
)
echo Total new request in Pool A is %NewPoolA%
echo Total renewal request in Pool A is %RenewPoolA%

echo Total new request in Pool B is %NewPoolB%
echo Total renewal request in Pool B is %RenewPoolB%
```

This is the logic and my understanding that how it will work. I dont know the syntax of dos batch commands.

These two pools are just example. I have total 80 pools for which i have to do this. In log file there are almost 100,000 entries. To match this number of lines to each of the pool will take too much time. So, the goal is to jump out of the 'if condition' after incrementing the value and to shorten the execution time of the batch file.

One more thing, the log file contains duplicate entries in different timings for same mac address. I need the increment will run only for unique entries of mac address.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('type "file.csv"^|findstr "^10," ^|findstr ",172.20.55 ,172.20.56"^|find /c /v ""') do set AAA-NewPoolA=%%a
for /f %%a in ('type "file.csv"^|findstr "^10," ^|findstr ",172.30.55 ,172.30.56"^|find /c /v ""') do set AAA-NewPoolB=%%a
for /f %%a in ('type "file.csv"^|findstr "^11," ^|findstr ",172.20.55 ,172.20.56"^|find /c /v ""') do set AAA-ReNewPoolA=%%a
for /f %%a in ('type "file.csv"^|findstr "^11," ^|findstr ",172.30.55 ,172.30.56"^|find /c /v ""') do set AAA-ReNewPoolB=%%a
set aaa
pause
```

Comment: +1 Nice, I was just about to suggest the same :-) Why complicate life, eh?

Comment: thats nice :) does findstr "^10," also match the IP in log file e.g. "...172.20.55.10,PC2...". This “10,” comes in IP address. Will it be a valid check to match ID? One more thing, I have checked the log file more thoroughly. It contains duplicate entries in different timings for same mac address. I have updated the above sample. I need the increment will run only for unique entries of mac address. This may require to create one more file that have unique entries for ID 10 and 11.

Comment: The `^` before the 10 means that the 10 has to start at the beginning of the line and will not match part of an ip address, but it doesn't handle duplicate mac addresses.

Comment: @foxidrive can you please help to handle duplicate mac addresses

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and fastest way to accumulate results when they are selected via complicated tests is to *not* identify each one separately, but accumulate all groups of related results and extract the desired ones at end. In your case, this is easily achieved via a *two dimensional* [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Accumulate results for all ID.IP (first 3 groups) combinations
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,5-7 delims=,." %%a in (log.log) do (
   set /A requests[%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d]+=1
)

rem Get desired results
set /A NewPoolA = requests[10.172.20.55] + requests[10.172.20.56]
set /A NewPoolB = requests[10.172.30.55] + requests[10.172.30.56]

set /A RenewPoolA = requests[11.172.20.55] + requests[11.172.20.56]
set /A RenewPoolB = requests[11.172.30.55] + requests[11.172.30.56]

echo Total new request in Pool A is %NewPoolA%
echo Total renewal request in Pool A is %RenewPoolA%

echo Total new request in Pool B is %NewPoolB%
echo Total renewal request in Pool B is %RenewPoolB%
```

You may also make good use of the flexibility that arrays provide to define your 80 pools in a much simpler way. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Accumulate results for all ID.IP (first 3 groups) combinations
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,5-7 delims=,." %%a in (log.log) do (
   set /A requests[%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d]+=1
)

rem Get and show desired results from a long pool definition list
for %%A in ("NewPoolA=10 172.20.55+10 172.20.56"
            "NewPoolB=10 172.30.55+10 172.30.56"
            "RenewPoolA=11 172.20.55+11 172.20.56"
            "RenewPoolB=11 172.30.55+11 172.30.56") do (
   for /F "tokens=1-5 delims==+ " %%a in (%%A) do (
      set /A %%a=requests[%%b.%%c]+requests[%%d.%%e]
      echo Total %%a request is !%%a!
   )
)
```

Output example with your data:

```
C:\> test
Total NewPoolA request is 2
Total NewPoolB request is 2
Total RenewPoolA request is 0
Total RenewPoolB request is 1
```

You may even replace the "NewPoolA" message in these results by "new request in Pool A" one using a second array! `;-)`

**LAST EDIT**

This solution has been modified several times because new details not included in the original question. In order to avoid confusions, I removed previous solutions and posted just the final one. The Batch code below accumulate requests for unique MAC addresses only, ignore MAC addresses equal to -1, and allows points in any field besides IP address.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Accumulate results for all ID.IP(first 3 groups).MAC_addr combinations
rem NEW: Ignore MAC_addresses equal to -1
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,5,7 delims=," %%a in (log.log) do (
   if "%%c" neq "-1" for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%i in ("%%b") do (
      set /A requests[%%a.%%i.%%j.%%k.%%c]+=1
   )
)

rem Get and show desired results from a long definition list
rem NEW: Only accumulate requests for unique MAC addresses (count=1)
for %%A in ("NewPoolA=10 172.20.55+10 172.20.56"
            "NewPoolB=10 172.30.55+10 172.30.56"
            "RenewPoolA=11 172.20.55+11 172.20.56"
            "RenewPoolB=11 172.30.55+11 172.30.56") do (
   for /F "tokens=1-5 delims==+ " %%a in (%%A) do (
      set %%a=0
      for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ('set requests[%%b.%%c 2^>NUL') do (
         if %%x equ 1 set /A %%a+=1
      )
      for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ('set requests[%%d.%%e 2^>NUL') do (
         if %%x equ 1 set /A %%a+=1
      )
      echo Total %%a request is !%%a!
   )
)
```

Comment: on execution it says Missing Operator :(

Comment: Total NewPoolA request is 2
Total NewPoolB request is 2
Total RenewPoolA request is 0
Total RenewPoolB request is 0  I think this result is wrong, using the `new` data in the question.

Comment: Missing operator error is coming due to this type of entries in log file "31,02/21/14,00:00:37,DNS Update Failed,172.17.110.13,TAR-CAR-051180L.WTPK.local,-1,"

Comment: This method create a series of variables that contains the ID,IP and MAC Address in their names and increment these variables with `set /A` command, so the names can NOT include any aritmethic operator, like the minus sign (your original example data have NOT these characters). Perhaps the method may be modified to manage this problem, but in this case I need a _complete_ description of the possible characters that may appear in these fields...

Comment: that arithmetic operator is the only possibility in that field. And second possibility is that the name filed contains . and - signs that i already mentioned in my previous comment. Thanks :) for your support

Comment: Is `-1` the only possible value with minus sign? How do you want to process these values: in the same way than the other mac addresses or just ignore them?

Comment: Yes, -1 is the only possible value and it comes with ID 31. Just ignore them.

Comment: This is strange. Previous code does _not_ mark "Missing operator error" with this data: "31,02/21/14,00:00:37,DNS Update Failed,172.17.110.13,TAR-CAR-051180L.WTPK.local,-1," because Host Name field include a point (not included in this field before) and the program use points as delimiters, so I had to modify the code. See the last edit above...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I'm sure you can work out the rest

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "NewPoolA=0"
set "NewPoolB=0"
set "RenewPoolA=0"
set "RenewPoolB=0"

for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (log.log) do (
  if "%%~a" equ "10" (
    for /f %%b in ('echo "%%e"^|Findstr /c:"172.20.55" /c:"172.20.56"') do (
      set /a NewPoolA+=1    
    )
  )
)
echo Total new request in Pool A is %NewPoolA%
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=. " %%a IN (q21935716.txt) DO (
 IF "%%d"=="" (SET $%%a=%%b) ELSE (SET #%%b.%%c.%%d=%%a)
)

FOR /f "tokens=1,5,6,7delims=.," %%a IN (q21935716.log) DO (
 IF DEFINED $%%a IF DEFINED #%%b.%%c.%%d (SET /a !$%%a!!#%%b.%%c.%%d!+=1)
)

FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%a IN ('set $') DO SET %%a

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a reasonably flexible routine, given that you have 80 pools.

The file `q21935716.txt` contains the following:

```
10 newpool
11 renewpool
A 172.20.55
A 172.20.56
B 172.30.55
B 172.30.56
```

Fairly obviously, lines of either ID+poolname or poolsection+IP.

The first step is to clear eny variables that start with either `$` or `#`.

Next step is to read the file `q21935716.txt` using `.` or `space`  as delimiters. This means that the poolname lines will have 2 tokens and the ip lines 4. The variables $poolname and #ip are then set up, containing the ID and poolsection respectively.

It's then a matter of reading the logfile, delimiers of `.` `,` or `space` which means tokens 1,5,6,7 are of interest. Only if $ID and #IP both exist is the line of interest. In tose lines, you need to increment the poolnamepoolsection.

The final `for` simply lists the poolnames.